# SVN change UUID

Tags: svn, uuid

I need to change my Repository UUID and I've found that the following command is what's needed to do so:

```
sqlite3 .svn/wc.db 'update REPOSITORY set uuid="xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx" where id=1'
```

When I run it I don't get any errors or confirmations and the uuid is not getting changed. Would anyone know why this is?

Answer (score 5):

You should not be modifying the SQLite databases inside the repository or working copy yourself. You'll just end up breaking it unless you know exactly what you're doing.

To change the repository UUID itself, use `svnadmin setuuid`. See also `svnadmin help setuuid`

To "change" the UUID of the repository which your working copy points to, you need to **relocate** your working copy to tell it where the new repository is. `svn relocate <newrooturl>` See `svn help relocate` for more detail on relocating your WC.

Comment: BTW - you can't relocate to repo with different UUID