# Export SVN repository with loads of revisions and import it as a new repository with a single revision

Tags: svn

Is it possible to somehow export huge SVN repository and load it as a single revision into the new SVN repository?

I already spent quite some time for research and couldn't really find a clear answer.

Examples always help so let's assume that we have a repository with 1000000 revisions.
Now I would like to ask if it's possible to export this repository and load it as a single revision into the new repository.

I know that svn doesn't support revision squashing like git does.
I know that dump and load commands exist.
I also know that this question exists [Why is a SVN dump of a single revision larger than a full dump?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8062691/why-is-a-svn-dump-of-a-single-revision-larger-than-a-full-dump)
But I'm not sure if I understand what's been said there

> "To ensure that the output of each execution of svnadmin dump is self-sufficient, the first dumped revision is by default a full representation of every directory, file, and property in that revision of the repository.
> However, you can change this default behavior. If you add the --incremental option"

Does it mean that if I dump the last revision, the resulting dump file will contain latest version of every file in my repository? Or will it contain latest version of every file which has been changed in this last revision? Could this help me achieve my goal?

My second option seems to be svn export.
I understand that it will export all files and directories but will they be in their latest version? In other words will this export contain the same set of files, directories and file contents as if I check outed HEAD revision in this huge repository?
If so then is there some easy way to load it back into the new repository with just one revision?
Something like svn export /path/to/repo | svn load /path/to/new/repo/containing/only/one/revision

I don't really care about the history and I care about the storage.
Does any of the above gets me even close to making 1mln revision repository into the new repository with just one revision?
Is it even possible to do something like that with SVN?
Maybe it's possible to do this with git svn?
I think it's going to be next on my research list if above ideas will fail.

Answer (score 2):

It is technically possible to flatten all the revision history of your M-revision repository into just one revision using `svnadmin dump` and `svnadmin load`, but this is impractical and is most likely unnecessary. Note that you will lose all revision history this way.

As far as I can understand, you just want to trim all revision history from your repository and get only the latest snapshot of your data. In this case, I assume that you don't need any of your tags and branches (or maybe only some of them).

Your idea about about using `svn export` is fine and should work better than with using repository administration tools.

1. Use `svn export` to download the latest snapshot of your repository (e.g. trunk/).
2. Create a new clean (empty) repository).
3. Use `svn import` to upload the data into your new repository.

If you have multiple projects, you can import them one by one into the new repository (I think that's the preferred method). You may also skip importing branches and tags, keeping only the trunk.

BTW, instead of having to `svn export` the data again, you could reuse the data from your existing working copy (if you have one one your computer).

I hope that the idea is clear.

Answer (score 1):

> Does it mean that if I dump the last revision, the resulting dump file will contain latest version of every file in my repository?

Yes, if used **without** `--incremental` option

> will it contain latest version of every file which has been changed in this last revision?

Yes, if used **with** `--incremental` option

> Could this help me achieve my goal?

Yes, but by the hard way

If you want to drop all history and transfer only HEAD into new repo (and you have SVN-client), you can just:

- svn up
- svn switch NEW_URL
- svn commit

Comment: The instructions part at the bottom of the answer looks weird to me. You will get UUID errors. I may be wrong, but AFAIK it does not work this way. Please, elaborate.

Comment: @bahrep - yes, you are right. I can't recall, how I got 2 repo with the same UUID decade ago

Comment: You can modify UUID, but I think that using svn export and svn import can be convenient.

Comment: @bahrep - found ancient answer for trick without dump|load (which are **slow operations** for big repos) https://stackoverflow.com/a/24638393/960558

Comment: there is svnadmin setuuid, but it should not be used in such cases. And such relocate operation in the context of the user's question is weird. Just export the data, clean up (remove) unnecessary files and directories, import the data into a new clean repository. That's it.